# XSLT dynamic form getting elements

Tags: xml, forms, xslt

I'm trying to make a dynamic form with XML and XSLT. My purpose is get a dynamic HTML code from my XML file.

I'm trying to get a value of an element but I can't reach it.

This is my XML:

```
<element>
    <id>7</id>
    <type>RADIO</type>
    <name>Sexo</name>
    <values>
        <value>Hombre</value>
        <value>Mujer</value>
    </values>
</element>
```

And this is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:if test="type='RADIO'">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />:
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="values/value">
            <input type="radio" name="{name}" 
                   value="{current()}" onchange="myFunction(this.id,this.value)" /> 
            <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
</xsl:if>
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
<td>Sexo:</td>
<td><input onchange="myFunction(this.id,this.value)"
            value="Hombre" name="" type="radio">Hombre
    <input onchange="myFunction(this.id,this.value)" value="Mujer"  name="" 
           type="radio">Mujer
</td>
```

How can I get the name in my html code? I have already tried using `../name` and `parent::node()`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a good and well-formed question, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have already tried using `../name`

`value` is the grandchild of `element` - so in order to select the `name` from the context of `value`, you need to go up **two** levels, then down to `name`:

```
<input type="radio" name="{../../name}" />
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

```
<input type="radio" name="{ancestor::element/name}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I thought I had already tried it but I might have written in a wrong way.